# What do you use to test Silverlight applications?

Tags: silverlight, testing

We are starting a big LOB application using Silverlight.

I was wondering if you have any experience with Testing Silverlight apps, what are the best solutions you found and if you encountered any pitfalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stalwart individual named Jeff Wilcox has developed a unit test framework targeting Silverlight 2 specifically.  It works well.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut/

I also use Rhino Mocks 3.5 For Silverlight as my mocking framework, developed by Oren Eini.  Rhino Mocks is free and excellent.  It also offers Silverlight support:

http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx

I use Prism 2.0, and Unity IoC, which help facilitate the MVVM pattern.  This makes testing a breeze.  One pitfall that I find, is that Silverlight unit tests run inside a web browser, which hampers continuous integration.

ib.

Comment: Hmm... A solution in a regualr testing framework would be something I would want but I guess that is too much to ask for at this point in time.

Answer (score 1):

A "must have" debugging tool for SIlverlight is [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/), available as a free download.

Comment: It isn't free anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly what you're after, but I subscribe to Netflix and they use the following url

http://www.tinyurl.com/netflixsl

...to send subscribers to when they've got a problem.  This is of course, at the end of things, and I'm assuming you're after something to test while you're actually developing.  But, this might be something you could copy once you're product is released.

Comment: Yeah, interesting but not what I was asking about. I'm more concerned during the development stage. I don't foresee us needing to have a customer facing test app for our product.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SilverUnit](http://www.codeplex.com/CThru/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SilverUnit%20examples&referringTitle=Home) to [unit test Silverlight](http://www.typemock.com/Silverlight_unit_testing_page.php), it is an open source tool that sits on top of [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/Silverlight_unit_testing_page.php)